# How to change the distance/radius from center that the objects are instantiated

Tags: unity-game-engine

How would it be possible to move the 8 instantiatedObjects "cubes" closer to the pillar.

```
public void instantiateInCircle()
{
for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
{
    float radius = 8;
    float angle = i * Mathf.PI * 2f / radius;
    Vector3 newPos = transform.position + (new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(angle) * radius, spawnHeight, Mathf.Sin(angle) * radius ));


    GameObject instantiatedObject = Instantiate(itemToSpawn, newPos, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0));
    instantiatedObject.transform.LookAt(spawnAroundThis.transform);
    instantiatedObject.transform.parent = spawnAroundThis.transform;
    instantiatedObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(scale, scale, scale);

     //this seems to work-ish , not sure if its good math but hey :)
     //Thanks BugFinder!
    instantiatedObject.transform.position = instantiatedObject.transform.position += instantiatedObject.transform.forward * distance;


    }
}
```

Ideally these could be moved closer to the pillar
[image]

Comment: Thanks BugFinder, this seems to work... not sure if it's right as far as the maths part goes? 

instantiatedObject.transform.position = instantiatedObject.transform.position += instantiatedObject.transform.forward * distance;

Comment: well as long as distance is how far you need to move in, it will be right.

Comment: hehe thats what I think too hehehe :P
Ps How do I mark it solved (by you) since you tried twice to help!
Help deserves points! Anyway thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the fact your code already points the object towards where you are trying to get closer, you need only move the object forward until its at the correct distance.

Answer (score 0):

Decreasing the value of the `radius` variable should spawn them closer to the pillar.

Since you are offsetting the cube position from the pillar position by the cosine and sine components of the radius, it will place them correctly spaced around the pillar.

Also, I believe

```
float angle = i * Mathf.PI * 2f / radius;
```

Should really be

```
float angle = i * Mathf.PI * 2f / amount;
```

The radius should not affect the angle the object is spawned, but the number of objects should.